# taking all values from a drop down except selected

Tags: javascript, html

After selection a value in a drop down I want to add new drop down under this with all values except selected one. Same way for third, fourth, ..... For third drop down values will be all from second one except selected value. All next drop down on such a way.

What is the way to do this in javaScript?

HTML elements...

```
<select id="president" name="president" type="text">
    <option value="0">Select President</option>
    <option value="1">Name A</option>
    <option value="2">Name B</option>
    <option value="3">Name C</option>
    <option value="4">Name D</option>
    <option value="5">Name E</option>
    <option value="6">Name F</option>
    <option value="7">Name G</option>
    <option value="8">Name H</option>
    <option value="9">Name I</option>
</select>
<select id="vicepresident" name="vicepresident" type="text">
    <option value="0">Select Vice President</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Loop through all the options in `president`. If its index is not equal to the `selectedIndex`, append an option with the same value and text to `vicepresident`.

Comment: Why would you do that BTW? What's the use case?

Comment: @AanchalSharma you can use this to avoid duplicate selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my result.........

```
<select class="slctfield" id="president" name="president" type="text">
    <option value="0">Select President</option>
    <option value="1">Name A</option>
    <option value="2">Name B</option>
    <option value="3">Name C</option>
    <option value="4">Name D</option>
    <option value="5">Name E</option>
    <option value="6">Name F</option>
    <option value="7">Name G</option>
    <option value="8">Name H</option>
    <option value="9">Name I</option>
</select>
<select class="slctfield" id="vicepresident" name="vicepresident" type="text"></select>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('.slctfield').on('click', function() {
        var i = $('.slctfield').index(this);
        var j = i+1;
        var $options = $(this).find('option');
        var $tempDiv = $('<div/>');
        $options = $options.each(function (idx, option) {
        if (!$(option).prop('selected')) {
            $tempDiv.append($(option).clone());
        }
    });
    $('.slctfield:eq('+j+')').show();
    $('.slctfield:eq('+j+')').html($tempDiv.html());
    });
</script>
```

here your can add more select field with 'slctfield' class.

Answer (score 0):

Put all your options in an array, pass them to 'president', then get the selected index and append all values except this one to the array for vice president.